# Is there some way to hide an interface widget through code?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to solve the problem of having only one model to update,  but with a **simplified interface** for younger students and a more complete interface for advanced users.    The advanced interface has too many sliders and switches on it for novice users, and it would only confuse them.

Is there any way to use code to ask the interface to hide a control?

Comment: Are you thinking of clicking on a button through the interface which updates the interface? Instead, why not just create a different netlogo file?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the error-prone maintenance burden of forking different branches of my model and trying to keep them in synch. Nicholas Payette's answer is a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xw` (eXtraWidgets) extension](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets) was designed for exactly that purpose. It allows you to create extra interface tabs and programmatically put widgets on them.

- First disclaimer: I am the author of this extension.
- Second disclaimer: though I have updated it to work in NetLogo 6, it has not been as well tested with recent versions, so there might be bugs here and there. If you stumble upon something, please [open an issue](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/issues) on the GitHub repo.

Note that there also used to be a [`goo` extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Goo-Extension/), but it has never been updated to work on NetLogo 6.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is a quick workaround to achieve what you asked, no code needed.

Group the sliders,etc. you want to hide and then cover them with the output widget. In this way you only need one model and you can add/remove the output widget depending on the audience.